# How to Convert List<T[]> to array T[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Is there a way to convert the `List<T[]>` to an array of the same type `T[]`?

For example: `List<class1[]>` to `Class[]1` ?

I know we can convert `List<T>` to array `T[]` using `list.Toarray()` but here I'm looking for 
`List<T[]>` to array `T[]`.

Comment: I'm guessing Java, but maybe another language? Please tag this question with the language you are using.

Comment: Why do you need this for both C# and Java?

Comment: So you want to flatten the list?

Comment: I need it only for C#, someone added the tag for java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be turning a List of Lists into one flat list.

If you are in C#, there are Linq utility functions for this:

```
// Namespaces you need
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


////////////////////////////////////////////
// In your code block                     //
////////////////////////////////////////////
List<T[]> myJaggedList = new List<T[]>();

// (Populate here)

T[] flatArray = myJaggedList.SelectMany(m => m).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see SelectMany method from list object

Comment: @User - You have to include System.Linq as a namespace. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Class `List` contains a function `List.toArray()`.  Here is the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()).

Edit: There is a generic `List.toArray()` as well `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` see the same documentation from above.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but it seems to me OP has a slightly different question: how to create an array (not an array of arrays) from the list *of arrays*